# Python suffix issue with xrange

Tags: python, loops

How can I 'format' my iterator in xrange to add a "normalized" suffix? Like "nice_name_1","nice_name_2", etc. My current iterator adds by 3 since I am using other for loop inside. Thank you

```
objs = ['pencil','pen','keyboard','table','phone']



for i in xrange(0, len(objs), 3):

    #...

    for n, obj in enumerate(objs[i:i+3]):
        print '...'

    #...
    print 'nice_name_' + str(i)

# Result:
...
...
...
nice_name_0
...
...
nice_name_3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print 'nice_name_' + str(i // 3)
```

or preferably

```
print('nice_name_{}'.format(i//3 + 1))  # start counting at 1
```

Comment: Thanks! why double '//' ?

Comment: '//' is integer division, the same as the default behavior of '/' in Python 2 - but in Python 3 '/' is floating-point division, ie  6 // 3 = 2 but 6 / 3 == 2.0